# svn cannot commit deleted file - it is out of date and path is not found

Tags: svn

First of all, I have tried all suggestions I found in other SO questions related to this.

I moved a folder and its contents:

```
svn mv Heuristics/EdgeProbSelector Selectors/.
```

Then I renamed the folder:

```
svn rename Selectors/EdgeProbSelector Selectors/ProbabilityEdge
```

Then I renamed all the files inside:

```
svn rename Selectors/ProbabilityEdge/EdgeProbSelector.hpp Selectors/ProbabilityEdge/Probability.cpp
```

This is where things broke. I got conflicts when I tried to commit. I had to resolve tree conflicts, by using (for many directories)

```
svn resolve --accept working /blah/blah
```

Now, **When I try to commit**, I get:

```
svn commit -m "blah"

svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File 'Selectors/ProbabilityEdge/EdgeProbSelector.cpp' is out of date
svn: Selectors/ProbabilityEdge/EdgeProbSelector.cpp' path not found
```

I have tried updating, resolving, touching and updating then deleting. Basically all recommendations from other posts, and nothing has worked, I still get this error.

I tried to touch the missing file, and then run update and then delete, but this problem still persists, with the error now being:

```
svn: Two top-level reports with no target
```

Before I try **very drastic actions** can anyone help?

Comment: What commit command did you use, and from which directory? Is it a parent directory for *all* these changes?

Comment: @Ben The commends are above. I made the mistake of not updating/committing between those commands. They were all from the parent directory. I have since nuked all changes (reverted) and did all from scratch, this time updating & committing in between changes, which worked fine.

Comment: I still don't see your commit command. I was also asking about directories in case you were not committing to high enough in the Dir tree.